# mathjax \textsc

Tags: mathjax

How do I get stuff like \textsc to work? Apparently it might be possible to enable it judging from [this mathoverflow answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1046/why-doesnt-mathit-work/).

Has anyone else found a solution that allows using small caps or caps at least?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

APSMathJax does not include a small caps font (since this is a text font rather than a math font), so doesn't have a `\textsc` macro.  You can simulate the effect with something like `{\rm S{\small MALL}C{\small APS}}`.  A bit of a pain, but if you don't have a lot of it to do, it should give you a result close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Too bad. But it might be sufficient with \newcommand. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `\def\sc#1{\dosc#1\csod} \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}` so that `\sc{SMALL}\sc{CAPS}` would produce the result I gave above.