# Org html export does not recognize custom latex macros

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a org mode file which has some custom macros like

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\opt}[1]{{#1}^{*}}
```

Sometimes I need to export the same document to html, where this appears as

```
undefined control sequence \opt
```

How should I define the same macro so that html exports can see them too?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717654/customizing-org-mode-exports

Comment: I had tried the approach in the above answer, but it did not work.
The macro was not recognized even when exporting to pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is incomplete solution:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand{\opt}[1]{{#1}^{*}}
#+BEGIN_HTML
\(
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{{#1}^{*}}
\)
#+END_HTML

\opt{2} - works for 'latex backend

\( \opt{2} \) - works for 'html backend
```

It needs a way to combine them. You have to escape macros with `\(` depending on backend, for example like in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12719168/1937596, but from that time org-mode changed API

Comment: Any way to take the `#+BEGIN_HTML` segment, save it to another file, then import it and still have it work like in your example?

Answer (score 2):

If applicable to you, you could try using Org macros in such a way:

```
#+MACRO: opt @@latex:\opt{$1}@@@@html:$1@@
```

That is {{{opt(...)}}} gets converted to:

- \opt{...} in LaTeX
- ... only in HTML